# Right meanings of 'form'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

> When legal decision-makers
>   like Justice Peckham, who are actually ...
>   making a policy or political choice act as if there were no choice
>   to be made—when they treat a policy choice as simply an exercise in
>   knowing the plain meaning of a word—their behavior is sometimes described
>   as formalistic. They act as if it is the **form** that matters, but in fact
>   it is substance that is doing the work.
>
> It is, to be sure, formalistic
>   to take the literal meaning of the words “prior to December 31” in
>   *United States v. Locke* as dictating a result other than what seems to be
>   the most sensible one, because it is to treat the **form** of a legal rule as
>   more important than its deeper purpose, or more important than reaching
>   the best all-things-considered judgment in the particular context of a
>   particular case.

Is it definition 1 or 4 or something else at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/form?q=form? I'm guessing that the meaning of form is the same in both examples?

Also, please explain your thought processes/deductive steps, so I can try to improve doing so and need not ask here?

Source: P30, Thinking like a Lawyer, Frederick Schauer

Comment: *ibid.* **form 4** [MASS NOUN] The customary or correct method or procedure: *an excessive concern for legal form and precedent* in contrast to the "content" or "spirit."

Comment: @Kris Would you like to recast your comment as an answer, for which I’ll happily upvote? Also, would you please enlarge on it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are looking for might be in the text sample you provide:

> It is, to be sure, formalistic to take the literal meaning of the
>   words “prior to December 31” in United States v. Locke as dictating a
>   result (...)

There are different methods of [judicial Interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judicial_interpretation), one of which is to primarily consider the *form* of a provision, i.e. the plain letter.

Comment: Thanks, but would you please pinpoint the specific definition that's right?

Comment: Definition 1.2 comes near, I think.